# How to instantiate a google map with GMaps function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Folks, good afternoon.
I do not have very advanced knowledge in Java Script, for Google Maps libraries. I need to resolve a later situation:
I have a following function:

```
function drawFreeHand1(map){
    //the polygon
    poly=new google.maps.Polyline({map:map,clickable:false});

    //move-listener
    var move=google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(e){
        poly.getPath().push(e.latLng);
    });

    //mouseup-listener
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'mouseup',function(e){
        google.maps.event.removeListener(move);
        var path=poly.getPath();
        //poly.setMap(null);
        poly=new google.maps.Polygon({
            map:map,path:path,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 1        });

        geojson = JSON.stringify(googlePolygon2geoJson(poly));
        console.log(geojson);
        $.ajax({
            url: "alerts.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: {geo: geojson}
        }).done(function(data) {    
   });

   google.maps.event.clearListeners(map.getDiv(), 'mousedown');

   enable()
    });
}
```

However, when running it presents the error of setMap not instantiated, being that a variable map is already instantiated in the code as global variable.

I believe you are not aware of the role, or make a reference in the same correct way in the function. Did you help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: If the map you've instantiated is as a global variable, why are you referencing the map as a parameter in the `drawFreeHand1` function?

Comment: In fact, it was an attempt I made, however, both with a passage of the parameter in the function, and without the passage the error persists. I do not know if there has to be, js?sensor=false:34 InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map